# How to categorize identical values into indicator?

Tags: r, range, indicator

Data set of people, gender and ages in a county. Trying to make an indicator for every person between the ages 18 and 25.

```
county$18_25 <- ifelse(county$age == 18:25, 1, 0)
```

However, when i run this code, only some of the people in the age range `18:25` get a `1` in the new indicator column of my dataframe. I can't figure out how it chooses who to include and who to exclude (example: only about 70 out of around 200 20-year olds get a `1` in the indicator column, no distinction between males or females).

Am I wrong to think that this code adds a vector called 18-25 to the county dataframe that assigns `1` to any person who has an `"age"` within `18:25`, and a `0` to anyone else? If so, how would I go about writing such a code?

Comment: Try %in% instead?

Comment: `==` runs in parallel across both vectors: 1st == 1st, 2nd == 2nd, 3rd == 3rd. You want `%in%`.

Comment: @GregorThomas `%in%` deletes `NA`s though.

Comment: @diomedesdata It's wrong, see my answer why

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
20 == 18:25
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The result is a vector of length greater than one, where you probably expect just one `TRUE`. So you need a different approach.

First, there's a **wrong solution** around using `%in%`: `ifelse(age %in% 18:25, 1, 0)`. The use is problematic though, since it deletes `NA`s, i.e. they will also get `0`! Just try `ifelse(NA %in% 18:25, 1, 0)`. I was also taught this first and had to suffer from it :)

### Solution

We can safely use `cut` for this.

```
res <- transform(dat, age_18_25=cut(age, c(0, 17, 25, Inf), labels=c(0, 1, 0),
                                    include.lowest=TRUE))
res
#    age           X age_18_25
# 1   49 0.082437558         0
# 2   37 0.514211784         0
# 3    1 0.390203467         0
# 4   25 0.905738131         1
# 5   10 0.446969628         0
# 6   36 0.836004260         0
# 7   18 0.737595618         1
# 8   NA 0.811055141      <NA>
# 9   47 0.388108283         0
# 10  24 0.685169729         1
# 11   7 0.003948339         0
# 12  56 0.832916080         0
# 13  58 0.007334147         0
# 14  60 0.207658973         0
# 15  46 0.906601408         0
# 16  20 0.611778643         1
# 17  26 0.379559241         0
# 18   3 0.435771585         0
# 19  41 0.037431033         0
# 20  54 0.973539914         0
```

**Note:** Don't start variable names with a number; this will only cause trouble. You might want to read `?make.names` on what is considered as valid names.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(age = c(49L, 37L, 1L, 25L, 10L, 36L, 18L, NA, 
47L, 24L, 7L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 46L, 20L, 26L, 3L, 41L, 54L), X = c(0.0824375580996275, 
0.514211784349754, 0.390203467104584, 0.905738130910322, 0.446969628101215, 
0.836004259996116, 0.737595617771149, 0.811055141268298, 0.388108282815665, 
0.685169729404151, 0.00394833879545331, 0.832916080253199, 0.00733414688147604, 
0.207658972823992, 0.906601407798007, 0.611778643447906, 0.379559240536764, 
0.435771584976465, 0.0374310328625143, 0.973539913771674)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```